# Setting 'codebehind' properties from within markup on ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

Placing the following code inside the 'markup' section on a web form does not work

Have I messed the syntax up or is something like this not possible on 'server side' controls?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" Text='<%#System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"]  %>' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$` [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx).

```
<asp:TextBox 
       runat="server" 
       ID="txt" 
       Text='<%$ AppSettings: foo %>'
```